# Why I new instance of child class and use function of a(), a() will run child class's function of b()?

Tags: java, oop

Parent class defines a() and b() functions, and a() function use b() function; then define child class, and override b() function in child class. Why I new instance of child class and use function of a(), a() will run child class's function of b()?

```
public class Parent {
    public void a() {
        b();
    }

    public void b() {
        System.out.println("Parent's function");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("Child's function");
    }
}

public class TestFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.a();
    }
}
```

Comment: why the result is Child's function rather than Parent's function?

Comment: Because otherwise it wouldn't be an override.

Answer (score 1):

This is how overriding and inheritance works. `Child` class inherits method `a()` from parent and overrides `b()`. So when you call `Child.a()` JVM sees that `Child` class has its own version of method `b()` and calls that version.
Check more about overriding here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm